# Accessing variable outside redis pipelining function on Laravel

Tags: laravel, redis, pipelining

I am trying simple redis pipelining command using laravel and have an issue :

```
$a = array("1","2","3");
Redis::pipeline(function($pipe)
{
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++)
   {
      $pipe->set("key:$a", $a);
   }
});
```

And I got 'Undefined variable: a '.
I think I am missing something here. Anybody can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This way you can make a variable to be visible within an anonymous function's scope:

```
$a = array("1","2","3");
Redis::pipeline(function($pipe) use ($a)
{
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++)
   {
      $pipe->set("key:$a", $a);
   }
});
```